# I want to add a value once but gets added twice and if i print the value first it only gets add once

Tags: python

the most important defenition is priemcecker, it checks if the number you gave in is a prime number by dividing the number with the first prime number: 2, if it has a decimal it will get the next prime number from defenition priemmaker but priemmaker only makes 1 prime number at a time for it to be efficient. if divided by the second prime number still has a decimal it will add the second prime number with the first prime number 2.

so if you want to check if 7 is prime it will first divide by 2, see it is not dividable so it will get the next prime number which is 3 and it will see it is still not dividable so it will add 3 to the list than it will conclude that 7 is a prime number.

the problem is that if you add a number it adds twice with this code which I think makes it less efficient.
I have tried a lot of things but i think the problem is in the defenition of priemcheker.

I have these exact results if I execute this code when I try it for the number 19

can someone say why it adds 3, 5, 7 and 11 twice.

```
def priemmaker (getal,lijst):

    for x in range (int(getal)):
        var2 = True

        for y in range (len(lijst)):

            if ((x+2)%lijst[y]) == 0:
                var2 = False
                break

        if var2 == True:
            lijst.append(x+2)
            break


    return lijst[(len(lijst)-1)]



def priemcheker (getal):

    lijst = [2]
    var1 = True

    while lijst[len(lijst)-1] < int(getal/2):
        if getal % lijst[len(lijst)-1] == 0:
            var1 = False
            break

        lijst.append(priemmaker(getal,lijst))
        print (lijst)

    return var1




def results (var1):
    if var1 == True:
        print ("het is een priemgetal")
    else:
        print ("geen priemgetal")


results (priemcheker(19))

[2, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 3, 5, 5]
[2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7]
[2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 11, 11]
it is a prime number
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not append in `priemcheker`:

```
def priemmaker (getal,lijst):
    for x in range (int(getal)):
        for y in lijst:
            if ((x+2)%y) == 0:
                break
        else:
            lijst.append(x+2)
            break
    return lijst[-1]



def priemcheker (getal):
    lijst = [2]
    while lijst[-1] < int(getal/2):
        if getal % lijst[-1] == 0:
            return False

        priemmaker(getal,lijst)
        print (lijst)

    return True




def results (var1):
    if var1:
        print ("het is een priemgetal")
    else:
        print ("geen priemgetal")


results (priemcheker(19))
```